# Keyboard shortcut to close the Find and Replace dialog

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, I type  `CTRL-F` to open the Find and Replace dialog.  I can search with `F3` or `ENTER`.  This brings me to the next hit, with the focus on the window where the text was found.

However, the Find and Replace dialog is still there.  If I press `ESCAPE` the window loses focus, but it doesn't go away.  I end up having to move my mouse to the small X on the top right like 100 times a day.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close the Find and Replace dialog?

Comment: @Dave Long: Thanks, great!  Would you know what the name of that command is, in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard?

Comment: think it's Window.CloseToolWindow

Comment: Ah, sorry, roadrunner already Answered...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use ..

```
Command Name            | Short-Cut Key  | Description
----------------------- | -------------- | -------------------------------
Window.CloseToolWindow  | SHIFT + ESC    | Closes the current tool window
```

Comment: I've never thought of Find and Replace as a tool window.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Press Shift + Esc. It will close the current tool window.

Answer (score 3):

1) Goto Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, in **Show commands containing:** type Window.CloseToolWindow.
2) Make sure Windows.CloseToolWindow is selected; remove the shortcut key (Shift+Esc)
3) Under **Use new shortcut in:** select Global.
4) Click the textbox under **Press shortcut keys:** and press **ESCAPE** key.
5) Click Assign
6) Press OK.

You are good to go :)